# Scala ParRange memory consumption

Tags: scala

I tried to implement iterative algorithm using range. It worked well so I tried to make it parallel using par method and it throwed *java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space*. I found that ParRange allocates a lot of memory in constructor. Is this correct behavior of ParRange? I would expect that it behaves similar to Range and allocates data only if they are needed.

You can easily reproduce it:

`scala> collection.parallel.immutable.ParRange(1, 50000000, 1, true)
  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I think you've found kind of a "bug".*

A bit more details.

1. If you take a look into OOM stacktrace more precisely - scala (for some unknown reason) is invoking simple `toString` method on `ParRange.scala:35` class. 50 millions numbers concatenated together into huge string gives you more than Gb and lead to OOM.
2. OOM is happening only while executing in `console`. Simple standalone app with `main` works fine (unless you invoke `toString` on it)...
3. What about `Range`? Indeed, same code with `Range` instead of `ParRange` works perfeclty. The reason is quite simple: toString method is overriden there, and do not try to output all elements, instead just first few...

I propose you following workaround to make your code work:

```
  def parRangeBuilder(start: Int, end: Int, step: Int, include: Boolean) = {
    new ParRange(
      if (include)
        new Range.Inclusive(start, end, step)
      else
        new Range(start, end, step)
    ) {
     override def toString = s"LazyParRange(${range.size})" // fix itself... 
    }
  }
```